# What does it mean Jesus was afflicted?

Tags: jesus, isaiah

In Isa. 53:4 it says, "Surely he has borne our griefs and carried our sorrows; yet we esteemed him stricken, smitten by God, and afflicted."
What does affliction here refer to? Could Jesus have fallen sick? Could he have caught a virus or flu?

Comment: Note of course that not everyone sees Jesus as the fulfilment of Isaiah. Most Christians would say the cross is the main affliction, but also that Jesus could have gotten sick. Theological questions like this are better asked at [christianity.se].

Answer (score 2):

**What does it mean Jesus was afflicted?**

Isaiah 53:4  (NET Bible)

> 4 "But he lifted up our illnesses,  he carried our pain;[a]  even
>   though we thought he was being punished, attacked by God, and
>   afflicted for something he had done."

**Afflicted by God.**

Most of the Jews and others at the time of Jesus did not understand the reason for his suffering and death. The passers were abusing him, the chief priests and scribes were mocking him and even the robbers were also abusing him.

**They also believed that God was afflicting him as if degraded and humiliated by Him.**

Matthew 27:38-44 (NASB)

> 38 "At that time two robbers *were crucified with Him, one on the
>   right and one on the left. 39 And those passing by were [a]hurling
>   abuse at Him, wagging their heads 40 and saying, “You who are going to
>   destroy the temple and rebuild it in three days, save Yourself! If You
>   are the Son of God, come down from the cross.” 41 In the same way the
>   chief priests also, along with the scribes and elders, were mocking
>   Him and saying, 42 “He saved others; [b]He cannot save Himself. He is
>   the King of Israel; let Him now come down from the cross, and we will
>   believe in Him. 43 He trusts in God; let God rescue Him now, if He
>   [c]delights in Him; for He said, ‘I am the Son of God.’” 44 The
>   robbers who had been crucified with Him were also insulting Him with
>   the same words."

The Jews charged him with blasphemy.

Mark 14:61-64  (NASB)

> 61 "But He kept silent and did not answer. Again the high priest was
>   questioning Him, and [a]saying to Him, “Are You [b]the Christ, the Son
>   of the Blessed One?” 62 And Jesus said, “I am, and you shall see the
>   Son of Man sitting at the right hand of Power, and coming with the
>   clouds of heaven.” 63 Tearing his clothes, the high priest *said,
>   “What further need do we have of witnesses? 64 You have heard the
>   blasphemy; how does it seem to you?” And they all condemned Him to be
>   deserving of death."

Comment: The primary affliction of Jesus was a mental affliction - a great fear of being separated from God the Father.  Hence the anguish in the garden and the cry, "My God My God why have you forsaken me?"

Comment: Dottard :The verse states that  It was the contemporaries of Jesus that believed that He was "smitten and afflicted by God" . The verse does not refer to Jesus's own mental affliction.

Comment: I think both are accurate! He was afflicted in every way — mentally, physically, even spiritually (through times of temptation by Satan, among other things).

Comment: I did not wish to suggest that Jesus' mental affliction was due to any mental illness only a mental torture.

Comment: Dottard : You are right that is how I understood it also, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I understand it in that way as well, and not only that this is something that had to be done for the sake of the saving of our souls, and to be forgiving for our sins once and for all there had to be a perfect sacrifice, once and for all and that was only thru God's son Jesus born of the virgin Mary that could happen.so there remains no more sacrifices for sins. Because he did it once and for all.

Comment: When the bible says if you think that you have eternal life think this again.what is it askually saying.